# Remover caracteres de um campo no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela onde tenho vários códigos, gostaria de pegar todos os códigos que iniciam com a seguinte sequência `1170` e remover a mesma.

Exemplo, o seguinte código `11701287871` ficaria `1287871`. Isso é possível?

Comment: Respondi como recuperar, mas se precisar alterar, acrescento a sintaxe do UPDATE, só avisar (na verdade é só um `UPDATE tabela SET campo = SUBSTR( campo, 5 ) WHERE SUBSTR( campo, 1, 4 ) = '1170'`. Faça backup antes ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR( campo, 5 ) AS restantes
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    SUBSTR( campo, 1, 4 ) = '1170'
```

A função `SUBSTR` (ou `SUBSTRING` ) tem essa sintaxe:

```
SUBSTR( valor, inicio [, quantidade] )
```

Se omitida a quantidade, ele pega até o final da *string*.

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```
SUBSTR( '11701287871', 5 ) = 1287871
             ^-- começa da 5 e vai até o fim, pois não especificamos tamanho

SUBSTR( '11701287871', 1, 4 ) = 1170
         ^-- começa da 1 e pega 4 caracteres
```

Manual:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: Valeu @Bacco, era isso mesmo!